# Modules shared between multiple projects in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, module, angular7

I have two projects that have the same "core" funcionality, for example they share the same layout and have same pages, but there are components and modules that are project specific, so currently I have 2 entirely seperated Angular project but when I change something in the core, I have to apply those changes to both project. How could I solve this problem? What is the common goto?

I already looked Angular libraries but they are only for some component that are shared between projects but not the whole application core.

Comment: I highly recommend you to look at [Nx](https://nx.dev/), which is there to address this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your hierarchical level of modules like:
[image]